# Symfony, proopgh, event soursing Error 42S02. Maybe the event streams table is not setup?

Tags: php, symfony, event-sourcing, prooph

Good day/night,
I'm really new in prooph event sourcing.
Try to understand how it works with symfony.

Take a look on this project.
https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do-symfony
What should I do with the DB in the beginning ?

I run the command
`php bin/console event-store:event-stream:create`
But get the error message :

```
Error 42S02. Maybe the event streams table is not setup?  
Error-Info: Table 'todo.event_streams' doesn't exist
```

For a moment I have the empty DB after the command

```sh
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

How can I setup them ? Is there some symfony command ? Or I need to do it manually ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow installation instructions. I assume you're not using docker? In that case you have to create the basic tables by hand. Please find instructions [here](https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do-symfony/blob/master/docs/installation/manual.md#33-event-store)

Comment: Exactly; I followed the manuel installation doc, now it's OK. Thank you. Do you know some community chats ? groups ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did not create the stream. 
Just followed this documentation, it's okay now

https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do/blob/master/docs/installation/manual.md